# Missing meta data for conan package buildInfo in Artifactory

Tags: jenkins, artifactory, conan

I tried to upload the buildInfo for my Conan package to Artifactory followed the guide in Conan official page. https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/howtos/generic_ci_artifactory.html
Everything looks fine except the missing of "Repo Path" in Artifactory.
As shown in the screenshot bellows:
[missing of repo path in buildInfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C001Y.png)
The repo path is always missing for Conan packages.
I tried to upload the package using jfrog cli or Artifactory Jenkins plugin and then upload the buildInfo. They can solve the Repo Path issue, but the directory structure will be very different than uploading it using "conan upload" command.

Comment: Which version of Conan and Artifactory are you using?

Comment: artifactory:v6.10.2
conan:1.14.4

Comment: I'm not sure about your case, but there is a new Artifactory version available: 6.11. Also, are you running Artfactory CPP CE ?

Comment: no, we are using Artifactory Enterprise

Comment: If you are using Jenkins+Artifactory with Conan I strongly recommend you to add the "Jenkins Artifactory plugin" (https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plug-in) and use the ConanClient to execute your Conan commands.

You may find useful information in this issue (https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/5553) where I'm adding links and sharing some Jenkinsfiles with the community.

Comment: Think you for your info, but we did use the plugin in our old pipeline. It can't actually solve the problem I mentioned above.